# Understanding File and Directory Permissions in Unix-Like Systems

Tags: command-line, permissions, kali-linux

I have a scenario where I own a file in a directory, and I'm trying to understand the interplay between file and directory permissions. Specifically:

If I am the owner of a file, do I need both write and execute permissions on the file and directory to modify or delete the file? Or is having write and execute permissions on the file sufficient to delete it?

In a case where I am not the owner of a file, but I have execute and write permissions on the file itself, can I still delete it even though I do not have write and execute permissions on the directory? What role do the directory permissions play in this situation?

I want to clarify when it is necessary to consider both file and directory permissions and when file permissions alone might be sufficient to take action on the file. My logic says "If the change is in the level of a directory, you must always check the directory permissions, then check the file permissions, Otherwise, only File permissions "I am confused

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials available online which would provide a more complete explanation than this site, which is mainly for specific problems/answers.

Comment: Kali or Ubuntu? It can't be both

Comment: ....and its not that hard to experiment yourself. But https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/#is-kali-linux-right-for-you

Answer (score 1):

> If I am the owner of a file

That's largely irrelevant

> do I need both write and execute permissions on the file and directory to modify or delete the file? Or is having write and execute permissions on the file sufficient to delete it?

- You need write and execute permission on the directory to create or delete a file
- You need no permissions on the file itself to create or delete it

> In a case where I am not the owner of a file

Irrelevant

> I have execute and write permissions on the file itself, can I still delete it

See above for permissions to delete a file.

> I want to clarify when it is necessary to consider both file and directory permissions and when file permissions alone might be sufficient to take action on the file

- You need permission to modify the directory in order to create or delete a file in it
- You need permission on a file to use its content
- You need execute (search) permission on its directory to be able to access a file

Answer (score 0):

Creating and deleting a file requires write permission on the file's **directory**. Writing a file requires write permission on the **file**.

Access Control Lists (ACLs) can change things, see `man -k acl`.